# How to find significance for Gini coefficient changes?

Tags: statistics, model-selection, gini-index

I'm using the Gini coefficient to evaluate the performance of a model.
Making some changes (feature selection, hyperparameter tuning, etc.) I created variant models with different Gini coefficients.

How can I prove that the improvement in the Gini coefficient is indeed statistically significant?

Answer (score 1):

In R there is a package called `DescTools` within it you can find a method for calculating Gini Coefficients, where you can set a confidence level, and get intervals back using a bootstrap method (simulation)

This is how I have seen it done, and probably as meaningful as you need in most situations because you can set alpha to be as conservative as you need.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.
Do you know if there is also a python solution?